# References in .NET Core (2.0)

Tags: .net-core, repository, entities

I've tried to add a new reference to my .NET Core project.The strange thing is that I can access also the projects that are involved in my reference. For this example, i should be able to see the Repository project from service, but should not be able to access Entity Project.However , I can still access the entities object from Service.

How comes ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References in SDK-based projects are fully transitive so - similar to many other package managers like npm or maven - you all the transitive references are available in the project to make sure the app compiles and runs cleanly, e.g. there are no unresolved references when the dependency is referenced and all assemblies are part of the build output and ready to run. (there may even be conflict resolution applied to conflicting version of assemblies resulting in the generation of binding redirects.)

In previous versions, you would need to install NuGet packages or add additional project references to other projects as well to not get build errors or type load exceptions.

Currently there is no perfect workaround if you want your project to do all the things needed to be able to run and resolve conflicts correctly but not pass transitive references to the compiler.

If you only need a dependency to build a project, but not to run it, you can mark a package or project reference as `PrivateAssets="All"` (add as attribute to the reference in the .csproj file).

If you want to enforce API usage - e.g. for layered APIs, consider writing a roslyn analyzer that will emit warnings if you reference APIs from places you don't want to. this may be suitable for large projects where tooling is needed to maintain the desired architecture.